Suricata rule for user based authentication
I'm new to Suricata, and I previously had a setup with a proxy that authenticated requests using usernames and passwords passed through Squid proxy. Now, we've transitioned to using AWS Network Firewall and Suricata rules to manage whitelisting. I'm looking to implement a Suricata rule to authenticate usernames and passwords, but I'm having trouble finding suitable content. Could you please provide some sample rules to address this scenario?

Could you add to the question, or describe here, the problem you're trying to solve? AWS Network Firewall (i.e. rebadged Suricata) is not an HTTP Proxy so won't support HTTP layer Basic Authentication or similar methods. Maybe the community can advise a different approach to your predicament.
